# convert list to inline with separators, not sure best way

Tags: php, jquery, excel, dreamweaver

not sure if this is the right place to be asking but i have a txt file list with about 11k entries but i need to convert into an inline list with | separators.... any one have any ideas on the quickest way to do this?

exmaple:

- line 1
- line 2
- line 3
- line 4

to be:

line 1|line 2|line 3|line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
file_put_contents("myoutput.txt", 
    str_replace("\n", "|", 
        file_get_contents("myfile.txt")));
?>
```

Comment: My bad. Missed a closing bracket.